# wrong number of factors

Tags: factor-analysis

I am supposed, based on literarture, to get 3 factors from a scale I applied. However, the exploratory factor analysis leads me to a 5 factor solution. Is there anything wrong? What should I check?

Answer (score 1):

If you were intending to test whether the previously proposed factor structure is correct, you want confirmatory factor analysis, not exploratory factor analysis.

If you really did you want exploratory factor analysis, and you're using new data, you shouldn't be too surprised to get a different factor structure. Exploratory factor analysis comes with no guarantee of consistency.